# Multithreaded Java applet bouncing balls and buttons

Tags: java, multithreading, button, applet, border

I'm trying to create a Java applet that bounces several balls within an applet window, each with its own thread and own button. How to add to each button thread with ball?

here is my code for the class BiliardBalls.java

```
import java.awt.*;
    import java.applet.*;

    class CollideBall 
    {
        int width, height;
        public static final int diameter=30;
        double x, y, xinc, yinc, coll_x, coll_y;
        boolean collide;
        Color color;
        Graphics g;

        public CollideBall(int w, int h, int x, int y, double xinc, double yinc, Color c)
        {
            width=w;
            height=h;
            this.x=x;
            this.y=y;
            this.xinc=xinc;
            this.yinc=yinc;
            color=c;
        }

        public double getCenterX() {return x+diameter/2;}
        public double getCenterY() {return y+diameter/2;}
        public void move()
        {

            if (collide)
            {

                double xvect=coll_x-getCenterX();
                double yvect=coll_y-getCenterY();

                if((xinc>0 && xvect>0) || (xinc<0 && xvect<0))
                    xinc=-xinc;

                if((yinc>0 && yvect>0) || (yinc<0 && yvect<0))
                    yinc=-yinc;
                collide=false;
            }

            x+=xinc;
            y+=yinc;

            //border
            if(x<0 || x>width-diameter)
            {xinc=-xinc; x+=xinc; }

            if(y<0 || y>height-diameter)
            {yinc=-yinc; y+=yinc;}
        }

        public void hit(CollideBall b){
            if(!collide)
            {coll_x=b.getCenterX(); coll_y=b.getCenterY(); collide=true;}}

        public void paint(Graphics gr){
            g=gr; g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval((int)x,(int)y,diameter,diameter); }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class BiliardBalls extends Applet implements Runnable
    {
        Thread runner1; 
        Thread runner2;
        Thread runner3;
        Thread runner4;
        Image Buffer;
        Graphics gBuffer;
        CollideBall ball[];
        AudioClip Collision;
        boolean collision;
        static final int MAX=4;

        Button a = new Button("A");
        Button b = new Button("B");
        Button c = new Button("C");
        Button d = new Button("D");
        boolean stop_a = true;
        boolean stop_b = true;
        boolean stop_c = true;
        boolean stop_d = true;
        boolean isClicked = false;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void init()
        {
                setSize(500,500);  
            Buffer=createImage(size().width,size().height);
            gBuffer=Buffer.getGraphics();

            ball=new CollideBall[MAX];

            final int w=size().width;
            final int h=size().height;

            try{Collision=getAudioClip(getCodeBase());}
            catch (Exception e){}
            ball[0]=new CollideBall(w,h,50,20,1.5,2.0,Color.orange);
            ball[1]=new CollideBall(w,h,60,100,2.0,-3.0,Color.red);
            ball[2]=new CollideBall(w,h,15,70,-2.0,-2.5,Color.pink);
            ball[3]=new CollideBall(w,h,150,60,-2.7,-2.0,Color.cyan);

            a = new Button("Run first ball");
            add(a);
            b = new Button("Run second ball");
            add(b); 
            c = new Button("Run third ball");
            add(c);
            d = new Button("Run fourth ball");
            add(d);     
        } 

        public boolean action(Event evt, Object arg ) {

             if (evt.target==a)
            {
                 if(runner1 != null)
                    {   runner1.stop();
                        runner1 = null;
                        a.setLabel("run first ball"); 
                    }

                else if (runner1 == null)
                    {   runner1 = new Thread(this); 
                        runner1.start();

                        a.setLabel("stop first ball");

                    }
                stop_a = !stop_a;

            return true;}

             if (evt.target==b)
            {
                   if(runner2 != null)
                    {   runner2.stop();
                        runner2 = null;
                        b.setLabel("run second ball"); 
                    }

                else if (runner2 == null)
                    {   runner2 = new Thread( this); 
                        runner2.start();
                        b.setLabel("stop second ball");
                    }   
                stop_b = !stop_b;

            return true;}

             if (evt.target==c)
            {
                   if(runner3 != null)
                    {   runner3.stop();
                        runner3 = null;
                        c.setLabel("run third ball"); 
                    }

                else if (runner3 == null)
                    {   runner3 = new Thread( this); 
                        runner3.start();
                        c.setLabel("stop third ball");
                    }   
                stop_c = !stop_c;

            return true;}

             if (evt.target==d)
            {
                   if(runner4 != null)
                    {   runner4.stop();
                        runner4 = null;
                        d.setLabel("run fourth ball"); 
                    }

                else if (runner4 == null)
                    {   runner4 = new Thread( this); 
                        runner4.start();
                        d.setLabel("stop fourth ball");
                    }   
                stop_d = !stop_d;

            return true;}

            else 
              return super.action(evt,arg);
         }


        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try {runner1.sleep(13);
    }
                catch (Exception e) { }

                for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
                       ball[i].move();} 

                handleCollision();
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        boolean collide(CollideBall b1, CollideBall b2)
        {
            double wx=b1.getCenterX()-b2.getCenterX();
            double wy=b1.getCenterY()-b2.getCenterY();
            double distance=Math.sqrt(wx*wx+wy*wy);
            if(distance<b1.diameter)
            {
                if(collision)Collision.play();
                return true;}
            return false;
        }
        private void handleCollision()
        { for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<MAX;j++) {
                    if(i!=j) {
                        if(collide(ball[i], ball[j])){
                            ball[i].hit(ball[j]);
                            ball[j].hit(ball[i]);}}}
        }
        public void update(Graphics g) { paint(g);}
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            gBuffer.setColor(Color.black);
            gBuffer.fillRect(0,0,size().width,size().height);
            gBuffer.setColor(Color.green);
            for(int x=0;x<size().width;x+=50)
                gBuffer.drawLine(x,0,x,size().height);
            for(int y=0;y<size().height;y+=50)
                gBuffer.drawLine(0,y,size().width,y);
            for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
                ball[i].paint(gBuffer);
            g.drawImage (Buffer,0,0, this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you make a small self contained example?

Comment: I need that when I clicked on the button "Run first ball" moving only first ball not all of them and so with all buttons ("Run second ball", "Run third ball", "Run fourth ball"). I want to add to each button thread with ball.